# line break in equation

Tags: equations

How do I get the line to break in an equation like in the example below between starName=name and birthdate=1960.

[image: Relational Algebra exmaple]

```
\begin{document}
$\Pi_{movieTitle} \sigma_{starName = name \wedge birthDate = 1960}(StarsIn \times MovieStar)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
$\pi_{\mathtt{movieTitle}}\sigma 
  \stackunder{\scriptstyle\mathtt{starName=name}}
    {\scriptstyle\wedge\mathtt{birthdate=1960}}
  (\mathtt{StarsIn} \times \mathtt{MovieStar}).$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses the `\substack` macro of the `amsmath` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \substack macro
\newcommand{\V}[1]{\texttt{#1}} % place argument in monospaced font
\begin{document}
$\Pi_{\V{MovieTitle}} \ 
\sigma_{\substack{\V{StarName} = \V{name}\\ \wedge\V{BirthDate} = 1960}}\ (\V{StarsIn}\times \V{MovieStar})$
\end{document}
```